# A CheckBox is checked. How to find which source checked the checkbox? User checked that or programmatically checked?

Tags: c#, winforms, silverlight

I have windows application or sliver light application I have check box in that application. We have two option to check that check box, 1)User will check by mouse. 2)programmatically we can check that box.
How to find which way to checked that box?

Comment: Could you elaborate on why you want to know that?

Comment: A checkbox is either checked or it isn't, you shouldn't really use them for things that have more than 2 options (your setting clearly isn't boolean if it's either checked, unchecked or checked by program). That sort of UI will confuse users.

Comment: Guys, I need this scenario. If I Click on the box shows a msgbox "Clicked by User mouse". If it is click by program  shows a msgbox "Clicked by Program Code"

Comment: What if they use a screen reader / other accessibility tool?  They could tab to it and press Space too, they could press Alt+shortcut key.  Be sure you know exactly what you're asking and *why*.  If it's done programatically, it's probably done to emulate a user.  If you're doing the checking programatically, the program will of course know that it did it.

Comment: Winforms or Silverlight?  The two technologies are quite different...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a logic. 
I can use events too when the particular check box clicked by Mouse or keyboard "Click" event, Actual code in the event is I can store some text (like "Mouse or Keyboard clicked") in Tag property of CheckBox. If the Tag property does not contain the above text or null mean, that CheckBox is not checked by Mouse or Keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

Besides that your question seems not complete, just mark a boolean variable when you mark your checkbox with the program...

Comment: My question is clear. Guys you all understand your exact my requirement.

Comment: Ok, just check a boolean variable to true when you do it by code, and false when the user do it.